# How to change commit dialog in WebStorm from dock mode to standard window?

Tags: interface, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Now I have commit dialog in dock mode:

[image: Commit dialog dock mode]

Version 2019.2 EAP

[image: version]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2019/06/webstorm-2019-2-eap-4/

> In WebStorm 2019.2, we are merging the *Commit dialog* with the *Local Changes* tab. That way, the commit action can nicely fit in the flow of reviewing the changes you’ve made in this tab. And you can always jump back to the editor, whereas with the old Commit dialog you had to close it first.
>
> The familiar `Commit` shortcut (<kbd>Cmd/Ctrl-K</kbd>) will now select all the modified files for the commit and focus on the Commit message field.

Solution:

> We understand that this new feature can affect your current familiar workflow. If you’d like to switch back to the old Commit dialog, simply deselect the **`Commit from the Local Changes without showing a dialog`** checkbox in `Settings/Preferences | Version Control | Commit Dialog`.

Answer (score 1):

In latest Version it now,
`Settings > Version Control > Commit` ,

Uncheck first option "**Use non-modal commit interface**"